# JSoup Frame error: this page uses frames but your browser does not support them

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, jsoup, frame

I want to access a frame through JSoup (on android) but the html is always like this:

This page uses frames but your browser does not support them
What should I do?
CODE:

```
  Document doc = null;
                    try {
                        doc = Jsoup.connect(url) .userAgent("Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8; U; fr) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52")
                                .get();
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    desc = doc.html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `userAgent` to the following so that the server thinks that you are a browser that supports frames:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Won't work :( The document loads correctly but the problem is when I connect to the iframe.
      Element iframe = doc.getElementById("blockrandom");

      String iframeSrc = iframe.attr("src");
            Document iframeContentDoc = null;
            if(iframeSrc != null)
            {
                try {
                    iframeContentDoc = Jsoup.connect(iframeSrc).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36").get();
}catch (IOException e){ }
}
            final String htmlstring = iframeContentDoc.html();